# Laravel cashier `$user->subscribed()` returning true when no subscription exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

My code is simple:

```
if($user->subscribed('main')){
    $user->subscription('main')->cancel();
}
```

I get this response:

```
Stripe \ Error \ InvalidRequest
No such subscription: sub_EQTvxKjit2Ak6i
```

The subscription was in fact previously cancelled, so it shouldn't be giving a `true` response.

I tried returning `$user->subscribed('main')` and it came back as `true`.

This user has other subscriptions, but 'main' is not active.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user->subscribed()` only checks the database for subscription status--it doesn't query the Stripe API at all. But when you try to cancel that subscription, then it queries the API.

So that could produce an error like this if your database is out of sync with your data in Stripe. Maybe your database has subscription from Stripe test mode, but you're querying the Stripe production API? Or vice versa?

Comment: in build mode, so data inconsistency is definitely possible and probable.

Answer (score 5):

**Update Cashier v13.4**

You can first sync the database entry with Stripe using:

```php
optional($user->subscription('main'))->syncStripeStatus();
```

Then call

```php
 if ($user->subscribed('main')) { ... }
```

Comment: you are champion!

Answer (score 1):

If you read **Billable** trait then you will find this function there

```
public function subscribed($subscription = 'default', $plan = null)
{
    $subscription = $this->subscription($subscription);

    if (is_null($subscription)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (is_null($plan)) {
        return $subscription->valid();
    }

    return $subscription->valid() &&
           $subscription->stripe_plan === $plan;
}
```

This function only checks subscription record exists in **subscriptions** table or not.
According to above function if subscription does not exist then it will return false.

Make sure you are not doing any mistake.